# How to draw the longest line through the center of mass of the contour

Tags: opencv, image-processing, geometry

I want to draw a straight line passing through the centroid of the contour, and then there are two intersection coordinates between the straight line and the contour. Finding the distance between the two intersection coordinates. I want to traverse each contour point, draw a straight line passing through the center of mass, make it intersect another point of the contour, and then find the two intersections with the longest distance. I used OpenCV to draw a straight line from the center of mass to the contour, but this is a line segment that does not extend to intersect the contour. Is there any good way to find the intersection of these two longest distances?

The purple line may be the result I want, while the green line is drawn by OpenCV.Please look at the picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a (manually drawn) image of the expected outcome?

Comment: I can't embed pictures directly yet. You can click "enter image description here" to view it

Comment: You don't have to embed the picture. I have seen the linked image but are you saying this is already the line you want to find? How is this the longest line? I would expect the longest line to go from center to bottom left.

Comment: This is not what I want. What I want is the coordinate distance between the two intersections of the contour and the straight line. Centroid is just a constraint. You can look at my latest uploaded picture

Comment: Understood. Iterating through all contour points, find the angle between this point and the center. Draw a long line with the same angle through one of the points onto a blank image. Then find the intersections by applying cv2.bitwise_and on the image with the contour and the image with the line. Calculate the distance between the intersection points and repeat with the next contour point.

Comment: **moments**. OpenCV comes with a moments function. this can help you calculate the **major axis** of a contour (also its center of mass). when you have that, you have the line's direction/slope. now you can calculate the intersection of that line with the contour (polygon). if you have a non-simplified contour (dense), you can calculate each point's distance to the major axis, and pick the ones that are closest... on opposite ends of the major axis -- or rotate the contour **upright** by that angle and then get that upright contour's bounding box.

Comment: i've inlined the picture. please let me know if the site prevents you from editing your question due to this.

Comment: @Olli, thank you! That's a good idea, but is there a function that can draw a long line according to angles and points? Opencv's line() function can only draw a line segment based on two points, which would be great if it could be extended into a long line

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz,Thank you for your help! I don't quite understand your method. Can you be more detailed?

Comment: I don't know of such a function, but if you just get the difference between the two original points and add and subtract this difference to one of the points, you will get a long line. Something like: 
`long_line_pt1 = pt1+(pt1-pt2)*10
long_line_pt2 = pt2-(pt1-pt2)*10`

Comment: I think the major axis will not necessarily pass through the two points with the biggest distance between them. For many simple shapes it will be very close though. And because I don't know what the post author needs this line for, it might suffice.

Comment: @user18889586 find the centroid point`(xc, yc)`, then calculate the distance to all contour points, then find the slope of all lines passing by centroid and contour points from line equation `mp= (yp-yc)/(xp-xc)`, the points that has the same slope belong to the same line, so you sum their distances, and finally find the max total distance.

Comment: @Bilal,Great! It's a good proposal. I think it can really solve my problem. thank you

Comment: Post the original input image. Here's an approach: load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold to get a binary image, find contours, draw contour onto a blank mask, find centroid of the contour. Now for each angle degree, draw a line and bitwise_and with the mask, this should leave you with the part of the line that intersects with the contour. Rotate for every angle and keep track of the longest contour line. Finally once it does a whole 360 degrees, draw the longest line onto the image

Comment: In my understanding of the contours functions, we should have a contour point at every kink of the contour and no points (except the end points) in segments that make a straight line. Therefore Bilal's approach might not work because it is not guaranteed that you will find two lines of the same slope. nathancy's approach will work. My approach is similar to this one but I assumed that the longest line will end in a inward kink at at least one of its ends. This is just based on a feeling though. nathancy's approach should be more stable.

Comment: @Olli, you are right.I tried Bilal's method. As you said, there are few straight lines with equal slopes. So I tried some mathematical methods and found some approximate results. They work well